# how to login using url in browser in php?

Tags: php

how to login using url in browser in php ?
I wonder if there is is a way to login by passing username and password to url ..
I search over internet but really nothing works
I know that it is not a good behavior but it will use in internal application.
I appreciate any help
Here is my login code

```
    elseif (isset($_GET['act'])
    && $_GET['act'] == 'login'
    && is_ajax()
    && isset($_POST['email'])
    && isset($_POST['password'])
    && !empty($_POST['email'])
    && !empty($_POST['password'])
) {
    $cookie_time = time() + (86400 * 30 * 12);
    $status = 1;
    $error = '';

    // change character set to utf8 and check it
    if (!mysqli_set_charset(db_connect(), 'utf8')) {
        $error = mysqli_error(db_connect());
        $status = 0;
    }

    // if no connection errors (= working database connection)
    if (!mysqli_connect_errno(db_connect())) {

        // escape the POST stuff
        $email = db_escape($_POST['email']);

        $result_of_login_check = db_query("SELECT `ID` ,`username`, `password`, `email` FROM `members` WHERE `email` = '$email' || `username` = '$email'");

        // if this user exists
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result_of_login_check) == 1) {

            // get result row (as an object)
            $result_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_of_login_check);

            // User ID
            $user_id = $result_row['ID'];

            // the hash of that user's password
            if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $result_row['password'])) {
                $salt = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(512));
                $hash = password_hash($salt, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32));

                db_query("UPDATE `members` SET `salt` = '$salt', `token` = '$token' WHERE `ID` = $user_id");

                $userid = ($user_id + 412) * 137;    // Crypt User ID with some basic math operations
                setcookie('key', $hash, $cookie_time, '/');    // Set key cookie
                setcookie('user_id', $userid, $cookie_time, '/');    // Set user_id Cookie
                setcookie('login_token', md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), $cookie_time, '/');    // Set user_id Cookie
            } else {
                $error = 'Wrong password. Please try again.';
                $status = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $error = 'We could not find any user.';
            $status = 0;
        }
    } else {
        $error = 'Database connection problem.';
        $status = 0;
    }
    echo json_encode(
            array(
                'stat' => $status,
                'error' => $error,
            )
        );
}
```

Comment: You can login via URL, but this is highly unrecommended. URLs are public and cannot be encrypted, which means that your password will be leaked the moment you use it. This would compromise every account immediately.

Comment: It is for internal use only .. please read my explination

Comment: Still everyone on your network will know all the passwords. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: It is just for experimental usage

Comment: I want to know the concept >> can you help in taht

Comment: You already have an answer below by Harish. What's wrong with it?

Comment: where to add Harish code in my code above ?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by passing the `username/email` and `password` via URL like this `https://example.com/loginpage.php?u=YOUR_USERNAME&p=YOUR_PASSWORD`, and can collect the credentials in your PHP code like this:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['u'];
$password = $_GET['p'];
```

But practically it is not good practice to pass the sensitive information via URL. You should encrypt the credentials before sending via URL and then decrypt on your login page,

Comment: In your page, where you will match username and password in database to check if user is available in database or not,